# Do Views degrade the EF query performance?

Tags: c#, sql, performance, linq, entity-framework

I was looking for some tips to improve my entity framework query performance and came accross [this useful article](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/entityframework/J8bO140912-Tips-to-improve-Ecntity-Framework-Performance.html).

The author of this article mentioned following:

> **09 Avoid using Views**
>
> Views degrade the LINQ query performance costly. These are slow in performance and impact the performance greatly. So avoid using views in LINQ to Entities.

I am just familiar with [this meaning of `view`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_%28SQL%29) in the context of databases. And beacuse I don't understand this statement: Which views does he mean?

Comment: IMHO EF itself is more likely to introduce performance issues through bad sql and lazy loading than anything a view will introduce!

Comment: It's possible, but you'll have to investigate how Linq actually handle the views, and even then it can be depending on the complexity of the view/query. I have seen other ORMs have significantly performance hit when using views due to how they handled the view, but I've not personally investigated views in connection with Linq/EF myself yet.

Comment: This question can't be answered without a concrete example. Views can give enormous performance boosts all the same. BTW, the "useful article" is gone now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's some pretty serious micro-optimisation in that article.
I wouldn't take it as gospel personally, having worked with EF quite a bit.
Sure those things can matter, but generally speaking, it's pretty quick.

If you've got a complicated view, and then you're performing further LINQ on that view, then sure, it could probably cause some slow performace, I wouldn't bet on it though.

The article doesn't even have any bench marks!

If performance is a serious issue for your program, narrow down which queries are slow and post them here, see if the SO community can help optimise the query for you. Much better solution than all the micro-optimisation if you ask me.

Comment: But isn't accessing retrieving data from a view not exactly the same as retrieving data from a table? Isn't it the matter of the database if queries are fast or not? I am using entity framework for accessing a view with many billion data sets. I have a great and fast database. So I was just wondering why a table would be faster.

Comment: If you've got a view with billions of entries, it's not going to be quick, whatever you do. A view is still a query really, albeit on multiple tables, so yeah, a query to one table vs. a query to a view is probably going to be faster, but if you need all that data combined into a view, then you've either got to do it with LINQ (potentially messy) or query the view, not really any other option.

Comment: Yeah, I agree. This sound logical.

Comment: A view is not a query, it's a description of part of a query. Either you're going to need all the work the view does—hence difference negligible—or the redundancy will be removed by the query planner—hence negligible. What differences using a view can make on performance in some cases has nothing to do with how many billions of rows you might have.

Answer (score 4):

It depends, though rarely to a significant degree.

Let's say we've a view like:

```
CREATE VIEW TestView
AS
Select A.x, B.y, B.z
FROM A JOIN B on A.id = B.id
```

And we create an entity mapping for this.

Let's also assume that `B.id` is bound so that it is non-nullable and has a foreign key relationship with `A.id` - that is, whenever there's a `B` row, there is always at least one corresponding `A`.

Now, if we could do something like `from t in context.TestView where t.x == 3` instead of `from a in context.A join b in context.B on a.id equals b.id where a.x == 3 select new {a.x, b.y, b.z}`.

We can expect the former to be converted to SQL marginally faster, because it's a marginally simpler query (from both the Linq and SQL perspective).

We can expect the latter to be converted from an SQL query to a SQLServer (or whatever) internal query marginally faster.

We can expect that internal query to be pretty much identical, unless something went a bit strange. As such, we'd expect the performance at that point to be identical.

In all, there isn't very much to choose between them. If I had to bet on one, I'd bet on that using the view being slightly faster especially on first call, but I wouldn't bet a lot on it.

Now lets consider `(from t in context.TestView select t.z).Distinct()`. vs `(from b in context.B select b.z).Distinct()`.

Both of these should turn into a pretty simple `SELECT DISTINCT z FROM ...`.

Both of these should turn into a table scan or index scan only of table `B`.

The first might not (flaw in the query plan), but that would be surprising. (A quick check on a similar view does find SQLServer ignoring the irrelevant table).

The first could take slightly longer to produce a query plan for, since the fact that the join on `A.id` is irrelevant would have to be deduced. But then database servers are good at that sort of thing; it's a set of computer science and problems that have had decades of work done on them.

If I had to bet on one, I'd bet on the view making things very slightly slower, though I'd bet more on it being so slight a difference that it disappears. An actual test with these two sorts of query found the two to be within the same margin of differences (i.e the range of different times for the two overlapped with each other).

The effect in this case on the production of the SQL from the linq query will be nil (they're effectively the same at that point, but with different names).

Lets consider if we had a trigger on that view, so that inserting or deleting carried out the equivalent inserts or deletes. Here we will gain slightly from using one SQL query rather than two (or more), and it's easier to ensure it happens in a single transaction. So a slight gain for views in this case.

Now, let's consider a much more complicated view:

```
CREATE VIEW Complicated
AS
Select A.x, B.x as y, C.z, COALESCE(D.f, D.g, E.h) as foo
FROM
A JOIN B on A.r = B.f + 2
JOIN C on COALESCE(A.g, B.x) = C.x
JOIN D on D.flag | C.flagMask <> 0
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT null from G where G.x + G.y = A.bar AND G.deleted = 0)
AND A.deleted = 0 AND B.deleted = 0
```

We could do all of this at the linq level. If we did, it would probably be a bit expensive as query production goes, though that is rarely the most expensive part of the overall hit on a linq query, though compiled queries may balance this out.

I'd lean toward the view being the more efficient approach, though I'd profile if that was my only reason for using the view.

Now lets consider:

```
CREATE VIEW AllAncestry
AS
WITH recurseAncetry (ancestorID, descendantID)
AS
(
    SELECT parentID, childID
    FROM Parentage
    WHERE parentID IS NOT NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT ancestorID, childID
    FROM recurseAncetry
        INNER JOIN Parentage ON parentID = descendantID
)
SELECT DISTINCT (cast(ancestorID as bigint) * 0x100000000 + descendantID) as id, ancestorID, descendantID
FROM recurseAncetry
```

Conceptually, this view does a large number of selects; doing a select, and then recursively doing a select based on the result of that select and so on until it has all the possible results.

In actual execution, this is converted into two table scans and a lazy spool.

The linq-based equivalent would be much heavier; really you'd be better off either calling into the equivalent raw SQL, or loading the table into memory and then producing the full graph in C# (but note that this is going to be a waste on queries based on this that don't need everything).

In all, using a view here is going to be a big saving.

In summary; using views is generally of negligible performance impact, and that impact can go either way. Using views with triggers can give a slight performance win and make it easier to ensure data integrity, by forcing it to happen in a single transaction. Using views with a CTE can be a big performance win.

Non-performance reasons for using or avoiding views though are:

1. The use of views hides the relationship between the entities related to that view and the entities related to the underlying tables from your code. This is bad as your model is now incomplete in this regard.
2. If the views are used in other applications apart from yours, you will be more consistent with those other applications, take advantage of already tried-and-tested code, and automatically deal with changes to the view's implementation.